# Python - Replace abbreviation in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

My dataframe has thousands of rows.
It look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
text = ['please send us a dm...','…could you please dm me','dm me plz…','i dmed u yesterday…','dm me asap thx', 'i send a dm to u now', 'thx u r so nice dming u now', 'just sent u a dm']
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": text})

          text
0   please send us a dm...
1   …could you please dm me
2   dm me plz…
3   i dmed u yesterday…
4   dm me asap thx
5   i send a dm to u now
6   thx u r so nice dming u now
7   just sent u a dm
```

I wrote a function to replace abbreviation in column 'text'.

```
def convert(dataframe, column):
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" dm ", " direct message "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" dming ", " direct message "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" dmed ", " direct message "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" plz ", " please "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" thx ", " thanks "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" u ", " you "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" asap ", " as soon as possible "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace("...", " "))
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: x.replace("…", " "))
```

However, my code is not working properly, so it can't fully replace all of the abbreviations in my dataframe.

```
convert(df, 'text')

          text
0   please send us a dm
1   could you please direct message me
2   dm me plz
3   i direct message you yesterday
4   dm me as soon as possible thx
5   i send a direct message to you now
6   thx you r so nice direct message you now
7   just sent you a dm
```

The desired final output would look like this:

```
          text
0   please send us a direct message
1   could you please direct message me
2   direct message me plz
3   i direct message you yesterday
4   direct message me as soon as possible thanks
5   i send a direct message to you now
6   thanks you r so nice direct message you now
7   just sent you a direct message
```

I can't figure out why my code is not working.

Comment: Include x.replace(" dm", " direct message") and x.replace("dm ", "direct message ")

Comment: You should probably use regular expressions instead of fixed strings. In the regexp, use `\b` to represent word boundaries,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First build a replace dict:

```
replacers = {'dm': 'direct message',
 'thx': 'thanks',
 'dming': 'direct messaging',
 'dmed': 'direct messaged',
 'plz': 'please',
 'u': 'you',
 'asap': 'as soon as possible',
 '...': '',
 '. . .': '',
 'r': 'are'}
```

Then use apply function to replace the abbreviation with the desired words. Finally merge the words back to a whole string.

```
(
    df.text.str.replace('[...…]','')
    .str.split()
    .apply(lambda x: ' '.join([replacers.get(e, e) for e in x]))
)

0                    please send us a direct message
1                 could you please direct message me
2                           direct message me please
3                    i direct messaged you yesterday
4       direct message me as soon as possible thanks
5                 i send a direct message to you now
6    thanks you are so nice direct messaging you now
7                     just sent you a direct message
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

see how here

```
x.replace(" dm ", " direct message ")
```

you use " dm " space in from and back

but in the list for example :

```
text = ['please send us a dm...']
```

there is a period at the back of "dm" so it doesnt replace it

Answer (score -2):

a cleaner looking approach would be to use a "replacement" dictionary and loop through the df and replacement dictionary..like so:

```
replacers = {' dm ':' direct message ', ' thx ':' thanks ',' dming ':' direct messaging ',' dmed ':' direct messaged ',' plz ':' please ',' thx ':' thanks ',' u ':' you ',' asap ':' as soon as possible ','...':'','. . .':'',' dm':' direct message','dm ': 'direct message ',' thx': ' thanks','thx ':'thanks ',' r ':' are ',}

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    for key in replacers.keys():
        df.iloc[i] = row['text'].replace(key,replacers[key])
```

although it will be a pain to list all the variations of replacements, e.g. ' dm' 'dm ' ' dm ' 'plz' 'plz...' etc...

you might have to look into some regex magic :)